# Finding the intersection(s) of a 3D parametric surface and a line

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, computational-geometry

I have some 3D parametric curve ***par*** and some line ***line***.

I want to find parameters ***u***,***v*** and ***t*** for the intersection points of ***par*** and ***line***.

I tried to do that with NSolve in many different ways and always got the following error message:

"This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve."

Below is just an example, but I'm looking for a method, **that works for every parametric curve and every line**.

Also I don't want to get ***x***,***y*** and ***z*** but ***u***,***v*** and ***t***

How to fix it?

```
Clear[u, v, t];
par = 5 {Cos[u], Cos[v] + Sin[u], Sin[v]};
line = {1, 2, 3} + {4, -5, 6} t;
NSolve[
 par == line
  && 0 < u < 2 \[Pi]
  && -\[Pi] < v < \[Pi],
 {t, u, v}, Reals]
```

Comment: `par = 5 {Cos[u], Cos[v] + Sin[u], Sin[v]};
line = {1, 2, 3} + {4, -5, 6} t;
Solve[par == line && 0 < u < 2 \[Pi] && -\[Pi] < v < \[Pi], {t, u, 
  v}, Reals, Method -> Reduce]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, `Reduce` is the most powerful Mathematica function for solving equations.

```
Reduce[par == line && 0 < u < 2 Pi && -Pi < v < Pi, {t, u, v}, Reals]
(* (t == AlgebraicNumber[Root[-18291750000 + 235480000*#1 - 237800*#1^2 + 
        48*#1^3 + #1^4 & , 1, 0], {0, 1/725, 0, 0}] && 
    u == 2*ArcTan[AlgebraicNumber[Root[-18291750000 + 235480000*#1 - 
        237800*#1^2 + 48*#1^3 + #1^4 & , 1, 0], 
        {3961/4536, -2479/1315440, 1121/353220000, 83/19073880000}]] && 
    v == 2*ArcTan[AlgebraicNumber[Root[-18291750000 + 235480000*#1 - 
        237800*#1^2 + 48*#1^3 + #1^4 & , 1, 0], {3505/1484, -9221/6455400, 
        17053/9360330000, 197/18720660000}]]) || 
    (t == AlgebraicNumber[Root[-18291750000 + 235480000*#1 - 237800*#1^2 + 
        48*#1^3 + #1^4 & , 2, 0], {0, 1/725, 0, 0}] && 
     u == 2*ArcTan[AlgebraicNumber[Root[-18291750000 + 235480000*#1 - 
        237800*#1^2 + 48*#1^3 + #1^4 & , 2, 0], 
        {3961/4536, -2479/1315440, 1121/353220000, 83/19073880000}]] && 
     v == 2*ArcTan[AlgebraicNumber[Root[-18291750000 + 235480000*#1 - 
         237800*#1^2 + 48*#1^3 + #1^4 & , 2, 0], 
         {3505/1484, -9221/6455400, 17053/9360330000, 197/18720660000}]]) @)

% // N
(* (t == -1.07503 && u == 2.29164 && v == -0.761533) || 
   (t == 0.116633 && u == 1.27311 && v == 2.30858) *)
```

The intersections can be visualized by

```
Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[par, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, 
        PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}],
    ParametricPlot3D[line, {t, -2, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}],
    ListPointPlot3D[{line /. t -> -1.07503, line /. t -> 0.11663}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

**Addendum: Use FindRoot**

In the event that `Reduce` does not provide a solution, `FindRoot` almost always will, but requires multiple initial guesses to obtain multiple intersections, as is the case here.

```
FindRoot[par == line, {t, 0}, {u, Pi}, {v, 0}]
FindRoot[par == line, {t, 0}, {u, Pi}, {v, 2}]
(* {t -> -1.07503, u -> 2.29164, v -> -0.761533} *)
(* {t -> 0.116633, u -> 1.27311, v -> 2.30858} *)
```

Comment: +1 You can tell `Solve` to use `Reduce`, e.g., `Solve[par == line && 0 < u < 2 Pi && -Pi < v < Pi, {t, u, v}, Reals, Method -> Reduce]`

Answer (score 4):

In general, first try `Reduce` as already mentioned. But some more difficult curves will not reduce or Mathematica will hang. For example:

```
par = {1, Erf[t], Cos[t]};
line = {1, 1/2, 0} + {0, 1, 1} s;
Reduce[par == line && 0 < s < 2 && 0 < t < 2, {s, t}]
```

Instead you can try minimizing the distance between the line and the curve:

```
result = NMinimize[{SquaredEuclideanDistance[par, line], 0 < s < 2, 0 < t < 2}, {s, t}]
(* result: {4.42622*10^-19, {s -> 0.399155, t -> 1.1602}} *)
{par,line} /. Last[result]

(* {{1, 0.899155, 0.399155}, {1, 0.899155, 0.399155}} *)
```

For your example of a line surface intersection `NMinimize` cam get trapped in a local minimum with the default method:

```
par = 5 {Cos[u], Cos[v] + Sin[u], Sin[v]};
line = {1, 2, 3} + {4, -5, 6} t;
NMinimize[{SquaredEuclideanDistance[par, line], 0 < u < 2 Pi, -Pi < v < Pi}, {t, u, v}]
(* result: {2.97068, {t -> 0.39428, u -> 5.45283, v -> 0.964654}} *)
```

Notice the distance 2.97 is too high. Try a different method to get a better result:

```
NMinimize[{SquaredEuclideanDistance[par, line], 0 < u < 2 Pi, -Pi < v < Pi},
 {t, u, v}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
(* {1.77932*10^-16, {t -> -1.07503, u -> 2.29164, v -> -0.761533}} *)
```

Comment: With my version 8.0 this works not good with standard method "NelderMead" for NMinimize. Have to choose other methods and in some cases higher WorkingPrecision. Your shown result isn't correct either.

Comment: I copied the wrong result - I mentioned this in a comment earlier that it would get stuck in a local minimum but I must have forgotten to put it here. I'll edit it.